# .NET Core Error when trying to access Microsoft's Identity Authentication database as Azure SQL

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database, database-connection

I have a .NET 5.0 web application that contains Microsoft’s Identity for login authentication. My application utilizes two SQL databases: a custom user database and a built-in aspnet database that is created/updated by Identity. The application runs fine on my local development machine and both databases are accessed without issue.  However, when I publish and run my app on Azure App Services and I try to access my Azure SQL databases, my custom user database works fine; but, trying to access my aspnet Identity database causes a crash. Note, both databases reside on the same Azure server, and share the same admin username/password. See app below.

[image]

When the New Person or List People menu options are selected, my code accesses the custom Azure SQL database, and all is fine.

[image]
 
But, when Register is clicked on the menu, the Identity code displays the following screen… so it appears that the Identity code is at least running.

[image]

However, once the  Register   button is clicked, and the Identity code tries to access its respective Azure SQL database, the application crashes. ..and yes, I do understand what this error message is telling me… but I am not running locally.

[image]

NOTE:  both databases (custom and Identity) that the application uses are Azure SQL databases and reside on the same server, and with the same admin username/password. Both connection strings are very similar (just different databases) and have been loaded into the Azure Application Settings connection strings. There is no problem accessing the custom database, but, the application crashes when trying to access the Identity database.
If you’ve seen this issue and know of a fix, I sure would appreciate if you could reach out and let me know the resolution.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks AnsumanBal-MT ...I'm new to this site, and I was having trouble formatting my question, as I intended. It looks much better now!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Guys ... I appreciate your help... I was doing some debugging/analyzing on the Identity registration code, and I came up with a temp solution... NOT recommended for production: if I connect to my Azure SQL Authentication/Identity database from my local workstation and run my application locally, it will run the necessary Migrations and create my database. on Azure SQL.. and now, my web application runs fine on Azure. And all this has led me to this link: https://tutexchange.com/how-to-set-up-asp-net-core-identity/  ...which is where I am currently at.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your project is not running under development mode so that it is not possible to for you to debug the code.
Check if the following steps solves the problem :

1. Set the environmental variable to IIS Server.
2. Add a Login to the SQL Server and set permission.

   You can check the [following document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) to create a Login.

Also check this [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2159501.aspx?Error%20An%20error%20occurred%20while%20processing%20your%20request%20) for related discussion.

Comment: Hey SauravDas-MT,